# How to receive a chunkedfile in netty 4 or 5?

Tags: netty

when I'm using netty to build my application, I got a problem that how to receive a chunedfile in netty. I have searched for days for a solution.

Netty has provide a ChunkedWriterHandler to send chunkfile, but it does not provide a receiver. I think a chunkedwriterhandler is a encoder so why there isn't a decoder ?

Answer (score 0):

why do you want Encoder for received bytes.
its a decoder which takes care of sending stream chunk by chunk. Its need to be installed in pipeline at sender side.
@ receiver side just received the bytes and play with them
for example

```
ByteBuf in = ...;
ByteBuffer nioBuffer = in.nioBuffer();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\test.txt");
FileChannel channel = fos.getChannel();
while (nioBuffer.hasRemaining()) {`enter code here`
channel.write(nioBuffer);
}
channel.close();
fos.close();
```

this will save the received bytes to test.txt (This code is for handler client end)